# Как сверстать такую таблицу?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.......................................................
.....................................................
...............

Comment: Grid'ы, например.
А вообще я бы не стал называть это таблицей, так что делать можно на чем угодно, хотя на флексах, хоть на флоатах.

Comment: с какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

Comment: @PauloBerezini когда задаю colspan='3' а внизу два td , верхняя сжимается до 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
table{
   width: 200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
}

.none{
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td  class=none></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td  class=none></td>
      <td class=none></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Это понятно, а так что бы было без пустых td ??